# How to rotate a video 90, 180 or 270 degree in android?

Tags: android

I am looking for program code that will do video rotation in android.

I had previously done image rotation using the following code.

```
bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aa_presell_ribs);

//Create object of new Matrix.
matrix = new Matrix();

//set image rotation value to 270 degrees in matrix.
matrix.postRotate(270);

//Create bitmap with new values.
Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

//put rotated image in ImageView.
imageView.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
```

I have searched on google and other sources but I'm not able to find such code.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) - it may be able to help you process the video on the phone. [Here are the instructions](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20compile%20FFmpeg%20for%20Android) on how to build it for Android.

Answer (score -2):

**You just Rotate the Image-view**

Like this...
But it will work API 11 and after that only...Cent % it will work

```
    imageView1 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView1.setRotation((float)90);
```

You just use the Video view replace the Image view

```
private VideoView videoView1;   
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    videoView1 =(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    videoView1.setRotation((float)90);

}
```

**That will work fine....**

Comment: ok but i want to rotate video. is there any way to video ration in android?